# Field positive ion emission

Tags: electric-fields, electrons, metals

A metal is approximately a sea of mobile electrons and a lattice of positive ions. In a vacuum, a piece of metal with enough negative charge [will release electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission). Sharp points enhance this effect.

But what about a *positively* charged needle? Will the ions at the surface be released into the vacuum (which would erode the needle)? If so, how strong a field is needed in comparison to electron emission?

Comment: If you are talking about *field emission* than you have to mention the electric field which tears electrons out of metal - without such field they will not leave.

Comment: A positively charged needle is one that has lost electrons already, and if anything, it will attract electrons from the outside rather then release ions (which are fixed in the lattice).

Comment: You mean a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_ion_microscope ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in realistic situations it is not possible to tear positively charged ions off from the surface of a conductor in significant numbers.  The electrons are loosely bound in an electron sea, while the ionic cores are much more tightly bound at part of the atomic lattice.

In fact, this is one simple way to design a diode, in which current will flow one way but not the other.  Biased one way, the electrons can leave the sharply pointed electrode, but biased the other way, there is no significant outflow of positive charge carriers.  The other electrode is made relatively flat to inhibit electrons from leaving that electrode as well.